# How are 16 rounds in DES connected?

Tags: des

The outputs of each of the rounds are connected how ? I am not able to figure out how the outputs are connected to one another

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is better suited for this type of question. If you ask there, please describe **in detail** what is understood and what not.

Answer (score 0):

They are connected by permutation and transposition; the output of the previous round becomes the input of the next round (and a few monkey wrenches), go to this website to see a graphical representation (http://www.cronospr.com/DES.php); it is just plain arithmetic!